# MiniDumpWriteDump fails with MiniDumpNormal but works with MiniDumpWithFullMemory

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, minidump, minidumpwritedump

I'm calling [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API from a top level exception handler from a local service app running on Windows XP SP3 like so:

```
_MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION ExInfo;
DWORD dwProcID = ::GetCurrentProcessId();
DWORD dwThreadID = ::GetCurrentThreadId();

ExInfo.ThreadId = dwThreadID;
ExInfo.ExceptionPointers = pExceptionInfo;   //Receive it from the exception handler
ExInfo.ClientPointers = NULL;

if(!pfnMiniDumpWriteDump(GetCurrentProcess(), dwProcID, hFile, MiniDumpNormal, &ExInfo, NULL, NULL))
{
    int nOSError = ::GetLastError();    //I receive 0x80070057
}
```

The above fails with the error code 0x80070057, but if I change the dump type to MiniDumpWithFullMemory it works just fine. Any idea why?

Comment: That error is E_INVALIDARG, which implies to me that passing 0 as the type is not supported for whichever version of dbghelp.dll you are using.  It's generally a good idea to supply a known good version of dbghelp.dll as part of your installation to make sure all of the functionality you need is there.

Comment: Very much appreciated. This seems to be the answer.